# Are event listeners identical to html events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is `onclick` in HTML identical to `.click()` in jQuery?

Obviously they are identical from a usability standpoint, but I am curious how the browser handles them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not the same. `OnClick` sets a property of a DOM element, where `.click()` adds an eventListener.

The differnce between them is that every DOM element can only have on property of a type at once. So if you use `onClick=` twice on an element, only last added will win, the first will be overwritten.

This will always alert 2, cause the first attachment will be overwritten:

```
myDiv.onclick = function(){alert('1')} 
myDiv.onclick = function(){alert('2')}
```

Using `.click()` or `.addEventListener('click', myFunction)`, you can add as many functions as you want. So the following will alert 1 and 2:

```
myDiv.click(function(){alert('1')}) 
myDiv.click(function(){alert('2')})
```

The differnt between jquerys `.click()` and `.addEventListener()` is, that the jquery solution works in all browser, cause IE<=8 has a different syntax (`attchEvent`). And that you can [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) all click handlers in once. The [normal JavaScript solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener) can only detach the passed function not all of them.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery attaches events using JavaScript behind the scenes.

An important difference is that jQuery allows multiple events to be bound using `click()`, where as you can only attach one handler using `onclick`. This is because [jQuery uses](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/255460e4836e86b86f48dd5b7d2a2cbf3f996de2/src/event.js#L108) either `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` behind the scenes, as opposed to binding to `.onclick` directly.

Furthermore, attaching handlers via JavaScript (using jQuery or not) promotes [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (i.e. not mixing JavaScript and HTML), which is a good thing.

Comment: You should see jquery `.click()` as some sort of API call, that makes sure your browser gets them. In this case they are handled the same (@matt correctly mentiones the multiple events), but it is not a given, as you let jquery handle the event. It might be different in the future? So they are on a different abstraction level.

Comment: I think you mean "unobtrusive" rather than "unobstructive".

Comment: The question doesn't say one way or the other whether `onclick` is used inline in the html; maybe devnill meant the form `someElement.onclick = function() {};` - isn't that unobtrusive too? (I admit that the OP's phrasing "in html" could be taken as meaning inline, but I don't think we can assume it.)

Answer (score 2):

(Noting that jQuery is a JavaScript library and so can't do anything that you couldn't do in JavaScript yourself if you had the time...)

The jQuery `.click()` method is different to `onclick` in a few key ways. In no particular order:

- jQuery endeavours to normalise the `event` object so that you don't have to worry about the (mostly) minor differences between browsers
- jQuery binds events with `.addEventListener()` or `.attachEvent()` depending on what your browser supports, so, again, you don't have to worry about the difference
- jQuery guarantees that where multiple handlers have been bound for the same element and event they will be run in the order they were attached (noting that using `.onclick` you can only bind one handler anyway, but with `.addEventListener()` and `.attachEvent()` you can bind multiple handlers)
- if you use jQuery's `.on()` or `.delegate()` (or the deprecated `.live()`) to attach events, rather than shortcut methods like `.click()`, it is easy to setup event delegation

Behind the scenes all the standard browser events are still happening, but jQuery provides a wrapper for them to make all of the above happen. Of course there are some other differences, but I see the above as the most important.

> Obviously they are identical from a usability standpoint

No they're not. It would be much more accurate to say that jQuery's events are (almost) the same as `.addEventListener()` or `.attachEvent()` in how you use them, but even then as detailed above jQuery gives you an extra level of abstraction to save you having to code it all yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the `.click()` even in JQuery is not the same. It is a piece of codes on top of the `onclick` in html. JQuery allows to bind methods to a event using this layer on top of the normal html events.

You can change/override `.click()` to adapt your needs. For instance when using a mobile browser or pda etc.